# Java Nullpointer exception while trying to open file on linux

Tags: java, linux

For one of my classes i need to write a Java sockets applet.

This part of the code i am about to show was already given, and no changes have to be made and it is confirmed to work on Windows machines.

However i cant get it to work on my Linux machine(Mint 18.3)

```
package bank;

import java.io.BufferedReader;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class RunClient extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9104605361596820718L;

    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        frame = new RunClient();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private RunClient() {
        super("Choose Bank Driver");
        Vector<String> vect = new Vector<>();

        try {
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Servers.txt");
            URI uri = url.toURI();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(uri.getPath())));
            String line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                vect.add(line);
                line = in.readLine();
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        final JList<String> list = new JList<>(vect);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(Math.max(10, Math.min(30, vect.size())));

        add(new JScrollPane(list));
        JButton b = new JButton("start");
        add(b, "South");
        b.addActionListener(e -> startBank(list.getSelectedValue()));
    }

    private void startBank(String arg) {
        frame.setVisible(false);
        frame.dispose();

        StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(arg);
        String[] args = new String[tok.countTokens()];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            args[i] = tok.nextToken();
        }
        Client.main(args);
    }

}
```

After debugging it I found  out that this line is giving me a nullpointer exception.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Servers.txt");
```

It works perfectly fine on windows machines, and yes my file exists and i have the rights to read it.

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Try `./Servers.txt`

Comment: `/Servers.txt` is literally `/Servers.txt`, not the local `Servers.txt`.  `/` is the root of the file system

Comment: But you're using getResource(). The path is relative to the java classpath, not the file system. Try using new File(path);. As getResource will return null if the resource does not exist on the classpath

Comment: `this.getClass().getResource("/Servers.txt");` *cannot* possibly throw NullPointerException. It's just returning null. It's the next line that causes the exception.

Answer (score 4):

When you use `getResource()` you are getting a resource relative to the classpath. That means to work, your resource needs to be *on* the classpath.

If you add the `resources` folder to your classpath, you will be able to reach `Servers.txt`.

Alternatively, move the `Servers.txt` into the `java` folder or use a file `File` or a file `URL` or `FileInputStream` to access the file directly instead of via the classpath.

By the way, it's unlikely to be the line `URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Servers.txt");` that's giving you a `NullPointerException`. It'll be the line after it: `URI uri = url.toURI();` where you dereference `url` which has a null value because `getResource()` returns `null` when it can't find the resource on the classpath.

Comment: thaks that worked now. any idea why the  code  above actually works for windows?

Comment: Cool, can you accept the answer? In answer to your question, it will work if the `Servers.txt` file is on the classpath. Either your Windows classpath was somehow configured differently or the `Servers.txt` file was somehow copied to a directory that is on the classpath (e.g. the `classes` directory).

Comment: It's likely that on Windows your IDE put resources/Servers.txt in the root of a .jar file and you were running that .jar file, whereas on Linux you were running straight from your filing system.